# Does indexing make sense to speed up the use of UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

I have a MyISAM table in MySQL with three columns - an auto-incrementing ID, an integer (customer id) and a decimal (account balance).

At this time, whenever I initialize my system, I completely wipe the table using:

```
truncate table xyz;
alter table xyz auto_increment=1001;
```

Then I repopulate the table with data from PHP. I usually end up having up to 10,000 entries in that table.

However, due to new requirements to the system, I now need to also be able to update the table while the system is running, so I can no longer wipe the table and have to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` and update the balances one by one which will be much slower than inserting 20 new records at a time as I'm doing now.

PHP only sends the customer id and the amount to MySQL - the other id is not actually in use.

So my question is this:
Does it make sense to put an index on the customer id to speed up updating given that the input from PHP is most likely not going to be in order? Or will adding the index slow it down enough to not make it worthwhile?

I also don't know if the index is used at all for the `UPDATE` command or not ...

Any other suggestions on how to speed this up?

Comment: Index will be used because you will have to use the `WHERE` statement to update a single row. Any time you do a search with `WHERE` it uses indexes. MySQL has to find the row, then update it.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Thanks, that answers that part of my question :-) I'm self-taught and use `JOIN` a lot and know that indexing helps a lot here, but didn't know about `WHERE`, so thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI learn to use the `explain` feature in MySQL it will help you a lot when dealing with indexes and optimizing your sql queries.

Comment: You also might be able to group queries where the balance is the same. In php you would loop over the data and store an array of ids where the balance is the same then loop over that and `update table set balance=$balance where id in ({$balances[$balance]})` or similar.

Comment: Are the customer ids unique? Or do you have multiple entries? If they are unique just make them the primary key. You don't need the auto incremented id column.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I can't 100% trust that the customer ids are unique because of the cruddy source from which I take them, and the balance is not likely to be the same for many customers. But I might remove the extra id since I checked and am really not using it at all. And I'll look into `explain`, too!

Comment: You could also consider what the difference between current value and new value is. If you can group updates by adding X amount you will still ultimately lower the number of queries that need to be run.

Comment: Here is a completely different method that might offer better performance. Perhaps you could save the values as a CSV and load them into another temporary table using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) then issue one update statement that references the temp table.

Comment: I'm dealing with a DBF file here, and the DBF data needs to be formatted a little before going into MySQL, and I don't think it's worth trying to figure out the difference - I just need the new value in MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what your update query is.  Presumably it is like:

```
update xyz
    set val = <something>
    where id = <something else>
```

If so, an index on `id` will definitely help speed things up, because you are looking for one record.

If your query looks like:

```
update xyz
    set val = 1.001 * val;
```

An index will neither help, nor hurt.  The entire table will need to be scanned and the index does not get involved.

If your query is like:

```
update xyz
    set id = id+1;
```

Then an index will be slower.  You have to read and write to every row of the table, plus you then have the overhead of maintaining the index.

Comment: Thanks for the code examples - they helped me better understand how indexing affects the database.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I'll make this into an answer. If you are saying:

```
Update xyz set balance=100 where customer_id = 123;
```

Then yes an index on customer_id will definitely increase the speed since it will find the row to update much quicker.

But for improvement, if you have columns (id,customer_id,balance) and customer_id is unique and id is just an auto incremented column get rid of the id column and make customer_id the primary key. Primary keys do not have to be auto incremented integer columns.

Comment: Also thanks to you - it sucks I can only choose one answer because yours also had very useful information...